# How to set Commander gem default command?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, command-line, console, command-line-interface

I'm using the Commander gem to write a small console utility.

I want to set a default command when user does not specify any. I found how to do through the API:

```
Commander::Runner.instance.default_command(:gui)
```

but I thought there would be a simpler and more straightforward way. I just can't find it using Internet search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's right in the docs, you should find what you need here https://github.com/tj/commander#command-defaults

It should be as simple as `default_command :command_name`

Comment: hey, somehow missed that although I've read that document to get started. Thanks!