# How to run common code before any command using Commander?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, command-line

I'm exploring the Commander gem using the [Modular style](https://github.com/tj/commander#modular-style) to run it.

My problem is that I want to execute initialization code after the command line options are parsed but before any command is run.

I'm calling the program by:

```
MyClass.new.run
```

I have an option:

```
global_option('-c', '--config FILE', 'Load config file.')
```

and I have a couple of commands, but I want to execute some initialization code just after the command line options are parsed so that initialization is performed before any command is run.

It seems to be impossible from what I read in the `#run!` [method source](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/commander/4.2.1/Commander/Runner#run%21-instance_method).

Any ideas?

Comment: This is very similar to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26486055/128421).

Comment: @theTinMan, I think it is a rather different question. Here I'm asking for a hook before executing any command. As I stated above this seems impossible.. so I need to run an initialization method within each command. The previous question was how to set a default command.